# Why won't this simple join work?

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join

I am trying to get the inner join to work where it takes the area codes from both tables and puts the city name next to appropriate series_id

```
 CREATE VIEW medical As
 SELECT series_id AS City, FORMAT(AVG(value),2) AS Average_CPI,     SUBSTRING(series_id,5,4) as areacode, cuArea.city_name, cuArea.area_code
FROM CURRENT
WHERE 
(
(
SUBSTRING(series_id,5,4) = 'A311'
AND SUBSTRING(series_id,9,8) = 'SAM'
AND period = 'M13'
)
OR
(
SUBSTRING(series_id,5,4) = 'A316'
AND SUBSTRING(series_id,9,8) = 'SAM'
AND period = 'M13'
)
)
GROUP BY series_id
INNER JOIN cuArea
ON cuArea.area_code = areacode
```

Comment: your question is not clear to me. Please can you explain what is error exactly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got the JOIN in the wrong location. It should come after the FROM.

```
CREATE VIEW medical As
 SELECT series_id AS City, FORMAT(AVG(value),2) AS Average_CPI,     SUBSTRING(series_id,5,4) as areacode, cuArea.city_name, cuArea.area_code
FROM CURRENT
INNER JOIN cuArea
ON cuArea.area_code = current.areacode
WHERE 
(
(
SUBSTRING(series_id,5,4) = 'A311'
AND SUBSTRING(series_id,9,8) = 'SAM'
AND period = 'M13'
)
OR
(
SUBSTRING(series_id,5,4) = 'A316'
AND SUBSTRING(series_id,9,8) = 'SAM'
AND period = 'M13'
)
)
GROUP BY series_id
```